# String to String[] of words

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to split a `String` and get the `String[]` of words. I tried this:

```
String[] plain = plainText.split(" ,;<>/[(!)*=]");
```

but in my case this doesn't work. After splitting, the array `plain` still has only one value and it is the whole string from the string `plainText`. My string looks like this:

```
<table class="content" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:540px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <tr>
                <td align="left" valign="top">
                    <font color="#666666" face="Arial, Verdana" size="1">
                    eBay Inc.<br />
                    2145 Hamilton Avenue<br />
                    San Jose, California 95125<br /><br />

                    Designated trademarks and brands are the property of their respective owners. eBay and the eBay logo are trademarks of eBay Inc.
                    <br /><br />

                    <strong>&copy; 2013 eBay Inc. All Rights Reserved</strong><br /><br />


                    eBay Inc. sent this e-mail to you at maximkr@gmail.com because you opted in to the eBay Deals Daily Alert campaign by signing up at ebay.com/deals.<br /><br />


                    Pricing: We compared the selling price for the featured Deals items on eBay to the List Price for the item. The List price is the price (excluding shipping and handling fees) the seller of the item has provided at which the same item, or one that is nearly identical to it, is being offered for sale or has been offered for sale in the recent past. The price may be the seller's own price elsewhere or another seller's price. The "% off" simply signifies the calculated percentage difference between seller-provided List Price and the seller's price for the eBay Deals item. If you have any questions related to the pricing and/or discount offered in eBay Deals, please contact the seller. All items subject to availability.<br /><br />

                    If you wish to unsubscribe from eBay Deals email alerts, please <a href="http://dailydeal.ebay.com/unsubscribe.jsp?s=4IwA&i=883690252203">click here</a>.
                    Please note that you are only opting out of the eBay Deals email alerts. If you are an eBay customer and wish to change your other eBay Notification Preferences, please log in to My eBay by <a href="http://l.deals.ebay.com/u.d?R4GrxGghJ4SpZccF_r3SS=21801">clicking here</a>. Please note that it may take up to 10 days to process changes to your eBay Notification Preferences. <br /><br />

                    Visit our <a href="http://l.deals.ebay.com/u.d?f4GrxGghJ4SpZccF_r3Sf=21811">Privacy Policy</a> and <a href="http://l.deals.ebay.com/u.d?KYGrxGghJ4SpZccF_r3SY=21821">User Agreement</a> if you have any questions.<br /><br />

                    </font>
                </td>
```

This is the part of the parsed e-mail message. So how do I transform this text into an array of words?

Comment: Which words specifically do you want included?

Comment: What should the array of strings look like? What is the expected output?

Comment: You mean you want the text neglecting the html tags?

Comment: Regular expressions are ***not*** the way to parse HTML. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: I need all the words which not consists any symbols. I need to check if some words are in this text. and if they are I will do some other things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex is wrong as some of its characters are regex control characters (e.g. `[`, `(`, `*` etc) and have to be escaped to be used as a split separator, also the whole group of characters have to be wrapped inside a []:

```
String[] plain = plainText.split("[ ,;<>/\\[\\(!\\)\\*=\\]]");
```

Read more on [Java regex here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum).

**Edit**: To follow up on comment from CPerkins, you could also use this regex:

```
String[] plain = plainText.split("[\\s^\\W]+");
```

What it does is it splits on all whitespace characters and all non-word characters, which is kinda what you want, I think.

**NB**: The above is only a direct answer to your question, there are much better ways to read/parse HTML.

Comment: An improvement, but that's going to yield multiple empty array entries from the whitespace, and newlines will count as text rather than being stripped.

Comment: @CPerkins thanks, updated the answer with a shorter/cleaner regex.

Comment: No worries.  Good answer. Nice and clean.

Comment: yes, you are right.finally I used `Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("(" + keyword + ")");
                Matcher mt = pt.matcher(plainText);
                if (mt.find()) {
                    reason = false;
                    System.out.println(mt.group(1));
                }` instead of all this

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Scanner class. You can read the words using a

```
while(scanner.hasNext()){}
```

type construction.

link: [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Answer (score 0):

What about some variation of [Apache StringUtils.split](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) ?